# How to apply multiprocessing to a sliding window

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am creating 1 million values and splitting them into train and test by using a sliding window that uses a window of length 1000 values and slides by one value every time.

For example, The first process would be the splitting of first 1000 values to the train, and 1001st value to the test. The second process would be valued from 2 to 1001 in the train and 1002nd in the test, and so on.

It takes 76.28 seconds to run the script. I used `timeit` to measure this.

Now, I want to reduce this time by running a sliding window using multiple processors. I used `Pool` from `multiprocessing` with 4 CPUs but, it didn't change the performance at all. I am wondering what could be a better way here?

code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()

data = list(range(1_000_000))
window_size = 1_000
splits = []

def sw(window_size, data):
    for i in range(window_size, len(data)):
        train = np.array(data[i - window_size:i])
        test = np.array(data[i:i + 1])
        splits.append(('TRAIN:', train, 'TEST:', test))

#  sw(window_size, data)
#  print(splits)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p= Pool(4)
    p = Process(target=sw, args=(window_size, data))
    p.start()
    p.join()

end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with train and test. But what I see is your staring only one (1) sub-process (despite your question talking abut multiple processes) while the main process waits for it to complete. So, you never have more than one process working. This could have been the main process to begin with so I fail to understand what the point of having started a second process was.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The first process would be the first 1000 values would be on the train and 1001 value would be in the test. The second process would be valued from 2 to 1001 in the train and 1002 in the test, and so on.

Comment: Yes, but how can we comment on **"Is this a correct way of doing it?"** when you are showing no code that actually attempts to run multiple processes? I suggest you look at class `ProcessPollExecutor` in module `concurrent.futures` The short answer is, "Not yet."

Comment: You just assigned a `Pool` to `p` and in the very next statement you clobbered `p` with a `Process` instance. Slow down, take a deep breath and look at what I suggested in my previous comment. You *can* use `Pool`, but you *didn't* do it. We all have our biases and I prefer `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Pool didn't really help with the performance.

Comment: You need to create some sort of pool and then `submit` in some fashion (the actual call depends on what type of pool is being used) multiple calls to function `sw`, each with unique parameters. For example, with `ProcessPoolExecutor` there is a `submit` function and a `map` function. With `Pool` class from the `multiprocessing.pool` module there is a (bewildering) assortment of calls you can make. You need to first read up on either of these (you know my choice) and understand how multiprocessing actually works before you attempt to apply it to your problem.

Comment: `Pool` didn't help because **YOU WEREN'T USING ONE** according to what I saw. The code you have as shown does not use pooling!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as the comments point out, all you do is create a Pool named `p`, then reassign that variable to a process result. I rewrote your sliding window function a little. A simple way to parallelize independent tasks is to specify what you want to do to one item and then just use the map functor. Benchmarks were performed on an `Intel core i5-6300U@2.40GHz`(dual core with hyperthreading).

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

NUM_EL = 1_000_000
WINDOW_SIZE = 1000
DATA = list(range(NUM_EL))


def window(start_idx, window_size=WINDOW_SIZE, data=DATA):
    _train = np.array(data[start_idx:start_idx + window_size])
    _test = np.array(data[start_idx + window_size + 1])
    # return something useful here
    return start_idx


if __name__ == '__main__':
    STARTS = list(range(NUM_EL - WINDOW_SIZE - 1))

    start = timer()
    result_single = list(map(window, STARTS))
    end = timer()
    print("Single core: ", end - start)

    start = timer()
    with Pool(4) as p:
       result_multi = p.map(window, STARTS)

    end = timer()
    print(result_single == result_multi)
    print("Multiprocessing: ", end - start)
```

```
>>> Single core:  99.9821742
>>> Multiprocessing:  38.71327739999998
```

*Note: This code most likely does NOT work in any environment using `IPython`.*